# acme.sh Issue Failed Due to nginx Cannot Start Due to No Cert

Tags: nginx, ssl, acme.sh

I'm trying to replace a setup from a previous version of `AlmaLinux 8.8` with `AlmaLinux 9.2`.  It's a web box running `nginx`.  I need to renew the certs, as it's a fresh new install.

The problem: I'm seeing that the `nginx.conf` has a bounce from port 80 to 443.  But since it has no cert, it won't start up.  Hence I can't get the `acme.sh` algo to work, as it relies on that last port.

Look for line 382 here:

[This is the full error in a gist.](https://gist.github.com/daBee/adc4fff7410f476ef6cbb7950e1d69c4)

How can I get this to work?  I've tried turning off `ssl` but it's the same issue.  Do I have to turn off the `port 80` redirect?  I forgot how I first got this working.  The `nginx` load test results:

```
nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/root/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/example.com.cer": BIO_new_file() failed (SSL: error:80000002:system library::No such file or directory:calling fopen(/root/.acme.sh/example.com_ecc/vexample.com.cer, r) error:10000080:BIO routines::no such file)
```